# How do you use mktemp to create directory in Makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make, mktemp

This is a Makefile piece of code of how someone may use mktemp in a Makefile

```
TEST=$(shell mktemp -d)
mktemp:
    echo $(TEST)
    touch $(TEST)/test.txt
    ls $(TEST)
    cat $(TEST)/test.txt
    rm -rf $(TEST)
```

This is an example output

```
❯ make mktemp 
echo /var/folders/62/wkysd_4n0w57ljl9ycfsd9cc0000gn/T/tmp.tQI5EeyW
/var/folders/62/wkysd_4n0w57ljl9ycfsd9cc0000gn/T/tmp.tQI5EeyW
touch /var/folders/62/wkysd_4n0w57ljl9ycfsd9cc0000gn/T/tmp.lVL3N8Rp/test.txt
ls /var/folders/62/wkysd_4n0w57ljl9ycfsd9cc0000gn/T/tmp.sBW9FzgD
cat /var/folders/62/wkysd_4n0w57ljl9ycfsd9cc0000gn/T/tmp.Ti53SWSw/test.txt
cat: /var/folders/62/wkysd_4n0w57ljl9ycfsd9cc0000gn/T/tmp.Ti53SWSw/test.txt: No such file or directory
make: *** [mktemp] Error 1
```

The expectation is that `cat /var/folders/62/wkysd_4n0w57ljl9ycfsd9cc0000gn/T/tmp.Ti53SWSw/test.txt` would not error.

How can mktemp be used in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
TEST=$(shell mktemp -d)
```

sets the value of the `TEST` variable to the string `$(shell mktemp -d)`.  It doesn't expand that string (doesn't run the shell command), it just keeps the string as-is.

Now, every time you use that value later in the makefile, it's expanded which means `mktemp` is run again, and you get a different value:

```
mktemp:
        echo $(TEST)
        touch $(TEST)/test.txt
        ls $(TEST)
        cat $(TEST)/test.txt
        rm -rf $(TEST)
```

You want to use [immediate expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) when you assign the variable, so that it is expanded only one time when the makefile is parsed; use:

```
TEST := $(shell mktemp -d)
```

Alternatively you can just write the recipe using shell operations and not use any make functions like `shell`:

```
mktemp:
        TEST=$$(mktemp -d) && \
        echo $$TEST && \
        touch $$TEST/test.txt && \
        ls $$TEST && \
        cat $$TEST/test.txt && \
        rm -rf $$TEST
```

Note by default each logical line of a recipe is run in a separate shell, so in order to have all the lines run in the same shell (so they have access to the same `$TEST` variable) you need to use backslash to combine them into a single logical line.

Comment: ... though the OP should be aware that the temp directory will then be created, unconditionally, when the makefile is parsed, not when the recipe for target `mktemp` is executed.  That may or may not be what they want.

Comment: The unconditionallity can be easily resolved by using target specific variable which I have edited into my question. since I can't paste formatted text in comments.

This answer is awesome. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Well, target-specific variables can have other side-effects: they are inherited by prerequisites for example.  Maybe you don't care about that in this case.  If what you really want is a temporary directory that exists only for the lifetime of this recipe it's probably better to use shell operations to do it rather than make functions like `shell`.  When asking questions it's best to be very specific about exactly what you want.

Comment: How do I invoke shell operations to call mktemp rather than make functions like shell?

Comment: I think you mean making calls outside make target.

Comment: A recipe in a rule is a shell script, so any shell operations can be run directly in the recipe.  I will update the answer.